# How can I find a collision for a toy hash function?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, hash-collision, birthday-paradox

I'd like to find a collision for a simple hash function below (python):

```
def hash_function(s=''):   # 'Hello World!' -> 7b2ea1ba
    a, b, c, d = 0xa0, 0xb1, 0x11, 0x4d
    result_hash = ''

    for byte in bytes(s, 'ascii'):
        a ^= byte
        b = b ^ a ^ 0x55
        c = b ^ 0x94
        d = c ^ byte ^ 0x74

    for i in [d, c, a, b]:
        tmp = str(hex(i))[2:]
        result_hash += tmp if len(tmp) is 2 else '0' + tmp

    return result_hash
```

here's also a js implementation [in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fufadi/edit?js,console)

I've found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594470/how-do-i-find-collision-for-a-simple-hash-algorithm), but the answer there wasn't quite comprehensible to me.

The length of the output of the function is always equal to 8. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` variables are integers that are converted into hex values in the end to form the resulting hash, i.e. `123 -> 7b`, `46 -> 2e`, `13 -> 0d` and so on.

---

So, could you help me with finding a collision for that function?

Comment: The result space is 32 bits, and there is the birthday paradox, so bruteforcing it should not be possible.

Comment: Sort of unrelated, but did you write this method yourself? Do you have any resources on writing toy hash functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to find pairs of strings that have the same hash is to generate random strings, hash them and store the results in a `dict`, using the hash as the key and the string as the value. If you get a hash that's already in the `dict`, print it.

I've optimized your `hash_function` slightly, and made the code Python 2 / 3 compatible.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from random import choice, randrange, seed 

def hash_function(s=''):   # 'Hello World!' -> 7b2ea1ba
    a, b, c, d = 0xa0, 0xb1, 0x11, 0x4d

    for byte in bytearray(s):
        a ^= byte
        b = b ^ a ^ 0x55
        c = b ^ 0x94
        d = c ^ byte ^ 0x74

    return format(d<<24 | c<<16 | a<<8 | b, '08x') 

s = b'Hello World!'
print(s, hash_function(s))

#ASCII chars that print nicely
ascii = b''.join([chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)])

seed(37)

found = {}
for j in range(5000):
    #Build a random 4 byte random string
    s = b''.join([choice(ascii) for _ in range(4)])
    h = hash_function(s)
    if h in found:
        v = found[h]
        if v == s:
            #Same hash, but from the same source string
            continue
        print(h, found[h], s)
    found[h] = s
```

**output**

```
Hello World! 7b2ea1ba
0944dbd0 TXN9 YXC9
105a9dce wA5> rA0>
7a29e4bd %+m' -+e'
7776b2e2 u&4u n&/u
7c3ea3aa D-\6 z-b6
6d46d1d2 `<r_ "<0_
6a26e0b2 ;;x8 ";a8
1033eda7 ,AwW =AfW
627395e7 #3@e ;3Xe
7d6ee7fa D,Hg `,lg
3c2bb2bf NmRc Cm_c
1e31b9a5 nOc[ oOb[
1a49f7dd MKv' ]Kf'
161beb8f )G\y IG<y
0247bbd3 !SX1 VS/1
```